# How do I rename a procedure with macros in Racket?

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

Let's say I want to replace all occurrences of an procedure at compile time, for example all occurrences of `cons` with . I tried two options that seemed natural:

### 1.

```
(define-syntax 
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ x y) (cons x y)]))
```

This works if I do something like `( 2 3)`, but I can't use  if it's not in application position, so I get a 'bad syntax' error if I do `(map  '(1 2) '(3 4))`.

Then I thought to just replace the identifier itself:

### 2.

```
(define-syntax 
  (λ (_) #'cons))
```

Now  by itself gives me `#<procedure:cons>` and `(map  '(1 2) '(3 4))` gives the correct answer, but with `( 2 3)` the syntax transformer is taking all the arguments and replaces the whole expression with `cons`, which is not what I wanted.

---

<s>How do I achieve what I want? Is there some kind of transformer that does this?</s>

UPDATE: As I typed the last sentence, I invoked the "Rubber duck effect" and found `make-rename-transformer` which is the thing I want. However, the docs say "Such a transformer could be written manually", and it seems I have failed to do so with my 2 tries. **How do you manually make such a transformer?** (ignoring the bullet points in the docs for `make-syntax-transformer`)

Also, I know I can just use `(define  cons)` but then that's a whole extra function call at runtime.

Comment: With `(define new-var old-var)` you do not introduce any operation at run-time. You are just defining that the same value has two different names, and you can use both of them without incurring in any inefficiency (you are just making your code more difficult to read). So if `old-var` is a function, by calling `(new-var arguments)` is equivalent to call `(old-var arguments)`, without any extra function call.

Comment: "that's a whole extra function call at runtime". Not really. Both bindings point to the same function so it's not wrapping as in `(define (de a d) (cons a d))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The absolute easiest (and probably best) way to do this would be to use [`rename-in`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._rename-in%29%29) to import an identifier under a different name:

```
(require (rename-in racket/base [cons ]))
```

This is also the most direct way to do it, since it won’t create a syntax transformer at all—it will create a new binding that is identical to `cons` in every way, including [`free-identifier=?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxcmp.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._free-identifier~3d~3f%29%29). From the compiler’s perspective, that makes `cons` and  indistinguishable.

---

However, this is a little bit magical. Another approach would be to manually create a [rename transformer](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html#%28tech._rename._transformer%29) using [`make-rename-transformer`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._make-rename-transformer%29%29):

```
(define-syntax  (make-rename-transformer #'cons))
```

If you can’t use `rename-in`, using a rename transformer is the next best thing, since the [`free-identifier=?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxcmp.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._free-identifier~3d~3f%29%29) function recognizes rename transformers specially, so `(free-identifier=? #'cons #')` will still be `#t`. This is useful for macros that care about syntax bindings, since  will be accepted in all the same places `cons` would be.

---

Still, this is using some sort of primitive. If you really wanted to, how could you implement `make-rename-transformer` yourself? Well, the key here is that macro application can appear in two forms in Racket. If you have a macro `foo`, then it can be used in either of these ways:

```
foo
(foo ...)
```

The first case is an “id macro”, when a macro is used as a bare identifier, and the second is the more common case. If you want to write a macro that works just like an expression, though, you need to worry about both cases. You cannot do this with `syntax-rules`, which doesn’t allow id macros, but you *can* do this with `syntax-id-rules`:

```
(define-syntax 
  (syntax-id-rules ()
    [(_ . args) (cons . args)]
    [_          cons]))
```

This pattern will make  expand as expected in both scenarios. However, unlike the above two approaches, it will *not* cooperate with `free-identifier=?`, since  is now a whole new binding bound to an ordinary macro from the macroexpander’s perspective.

---

From that point of view, is `make-rename-transformer` magical? Not really, but it is special in the sense that `free-identifier=?` handles it as a special case. If you wanted to, you could implement your own `make-rename-transformer` function and your own `free-identifier=?` function to get similar behavior:

```
(begin-for-syntax
  (struct my-rename-transformer (id-stx)
    #:property prop:procedure
    (λ (self stx)
      (with-syntax ([id (my-rename-transformer-id-stx self)])
        ((set!-transformer-procedure
          (syntax-id-rules ()
            [(_ . args) (id . args)]
            [_          id]))
         stx))))

  (define (my-rename-target id-stx)
    (let ([val (syntax-local-value id-stx (λ () #f))])
      (if (my-rename-transformer? val)
          (my-rename-target (my-rename-transformer-id-stx val))
          id-stx)))

  (define (my-free-identifier=? id-a id-b)
    (free-identifier=? (my-rename-target id-a)
                       (my-rename-target id-b))))
```

This will allow you to do this:

```
(define-syntax  (my-rename-transformer #'cons))
```

…and `(my-free-identifier=? #' #'cons)` will be `#t`. However, it’s not recommended that you *actually* do this, for obvious reasons: not only is it unnecessary, it won’t really work, given that other macros won’t use `my-free-identifier=?`, just the ordinary `free-identifier=?`. For that reason, it’s highly recommended that you just use `make-rename-transformer` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you manually want to write such a macro, you need to use `make-set!-transformer`.

[http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html?q=set-transformer#%28def.*%28%28quote.*~23~25kernel%29._make-set%21-transformer%29%29](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html?q=set-transformer#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._make-set%21-transformer%29%29)

Note that you need to handle both assignments `(set! x e)` and references `x` and  applications `(x arg0 arg1 ...)` needs to be handled by the clauses in your `syntax-case` expression.

UPDATE

In Dybvig's book "The Scheme Programming Language" he has an example of a macro `define-integrable` that sounds to be just the thing you are after.

http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/syntax.html#./syntax:s61